# Smart app banner not calling application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I've implemented Smart app banner in my website. However, it is not calling the method `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` from my `UIApplicationDelegate` when tapping the button **OPEN**.

The AppStore ID is correct. I downloaded my app from the AppStore, then build a new version with Xcode so I can invoke my app via smart app banner

Meta data in html:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=457505507, app-argument=FiveStar://detail/?id=8393">
```

Anyone is having the same problem? Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: the code is appended d

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on iOS 6 ?
I have the same issue, openURL:sourceApplication is not being called on iOS 7, still works as expected on iOS 6.. can't figure out why for now...

Comment: not yet, I don't have iOS6 anymore, I have tried some app that has been on AppStore, they have the same problem, it seems a bug

Comment: This is a known bug on iOS7 (still not resolved on 7.0.4). [link]https://devforums.apple.com/message/897373#897373